# VeeValidate for v-menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

Is there any way to apply veevalidate for vuetify's v-menu?

I'm using validation-provider container. I've tried this on other html inputs and its working, but not on `v-menu`. and I can't find any source to solve this issue.
Anyone who encountered the same issue?

```
<ValidationObserver v-slot="{ handleSubmit }">
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(_submit)">
        <validation-provider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
            <v-menu width="300" max-height="400">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <b-input-group v-on="on" v-bind="attrs" class="mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <b-input-group-prepend>
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
                            <i class="i-Music-Note-2 text-18"></i>
                        </span>
                    </b-input-group-prepend>
                    <b-form-select id="inline-form-input-username"></b-form-select>
                    <span class="text-red">{{errors[0]}}</span>
                </b-input-group>
            </template> 
            <template v-for="items in item_list">
                <p>{{item.name}}</p>
            </template>
        </v-menu>
        </validation-provider>
    </form>
</ValidationObserver>
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation, the `ValidationProvider` looks for the first `v-model` or `value` occurrence and watches them between re-renders to validate them.

If your `v-menu` doesn't use `v-model` or doesn't include a node that does, then vee-validate won't be able to pick anything up.

You can handle validation on your own with the `validate` method, which you can call on any event you would like, given that they emit the input value in that event.

```html
<validation-provider rules="required" v-slot="{ errors, validate }">
  <someNode @input="validate" />
</validation-provider>
```

Comment: Thank you, dear @logaretm ! Is it possible to find out what exact child/node/element the provider watches/listens to? Considering the source code https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/v3/src/components/common.ts#L167 , it seems VeeValidate does not store the `v-model` Node found but just adds "native" or Vue-like listeners to handle. For example, it would allow to focus on the invalid field if it does not have `name` nor `id` prop or attribute.